# Triggering an event from one jQuery plugin and catching it in another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I currently have two plugins, written according the jquery guidelines here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

What is the best practice way to raise a namespaced event from one plugin and then catch it in another? I've set up a cut-down version of the situation in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cMfA7/ - the HTML and Javascript is below:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <button id="click">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
/* ===========================
    Plugin that triggers event:
   =========================== */
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
     init : function( options ) {

       return this.each(function(){
         $("#click").bind('click.pluginTrigger', methods.trigger);
       });

     },
     trigger : function( ) { 
         // TODO: Trigger to go here?

     }
  };

  $.fn.pluginTrigger = function( method ) {

    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

/* ===========================
    Plugin that handles event:
   =========================== */
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
     init : function( options ) {

       return this.each(function(){
           // TODO: Binding on pluginTrigger event to go here (and call methods.result method below)?

       });

     },
     result : function( ) { 
        $("#result").text("Received!");
     }
  };

  $.fn.pluginBinder = function( method ) {

    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

/* ===============
    Initialisation
   =============== */
$("#container").pluginTrigger();
$("#container").pluginBinder();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespacing doesn't really apply.  The only requirement is that the 2 plugins agree to the name of the event.  My suggestion is for the plugin that triggers the event to have a variable with the name of the event.  Then the consumer can use that name:

```
// within your pluginTrigger plugin
var eventName = "pluginTriggerEvent";
$.fn.pluginTrigger.eventName = eventName;

// within your trigger method:
$(this).trigger(eventName);

// -------------------------------
// within your pluginBinder plugin init method:
$(this).on($.fn.pluginTrigger.eventName, methods.result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that seems a neat way of doing it.